# when i test my trigger the error will shows Given below

Tags: trigger, unit-test, class

Everyone

When I test my trigger  class the error will shows Given below

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [Description__c]: [Description__c]

```
@isTest
private class TestHandleProductPriceChange {

static testMethod void testPriceChange() {
     Invoice_Statement__c invoice = new Invoice_Statement__c
            (Status__c = 'Negotiating');
     insert invoice; 

     Merchandise__c[] products = new Merchandise__c[]{
        new Merchandise__c(Name = 'item 1', Description__c = 
    'test product 1', Price__c = 10,Total_Inventory__c = 10),
        new Merchandise__c(Name = 'item 2', Description__c = 
    'test product 2', Price__c = 11,Total_Inventory__c = 10)
      };
      insert products; 
      Line_Item__c[] lineItems = new Line_Item__c[] {
          new Line_Item__c(Invoice_Statement__c = invoice.id,
 Merchandise__c = products[0].id,Unit_Price__c = 10, Units_Sold__c = 3),
           new Line_Item__c(Invoice_Statement__c = invoice.id,
 Merchandise__c = products[1].id,Unit_Price__c = 11, Units_Sold__c = 6)
      };
      insert lineItems; 

      products[0].price__c = 20;
      Test.startTest();
      update products;
      Test.stopTest();

     lineItems = [SELECT id, unit_price__c FROM Line_Item__c WHERE id IN :lineItems];

     system.assert(lineItems[0].unit_price__c == 10);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That error is telling you that the `Description__c` is missing. You need to add this field to your test in order to compile this code. Take a look to your objects and make sure that you find out which of this objects has the 
`Description__c` as a mandatory field. Then get back to your code and add the field to your logic. It is best to use a TestFactory to get control of these things.